# Prove that $(1,2)$ is an open set

Tags: real-analysis

I have the definition of an open set as:
Let $O\subseteq\mathbb R$ We say $O$ is open if for every $c\in O$, there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $B_\epsilon=\{x\in\mathbb R:|x-c|<\epsilon\} = (c-\epsilon,c+\epsilon)$ is contained in $O$.

Comment: Questions posted here should generally not be phrased in language suitable for assigning homework.  Saying "Here this problem, please solve it." is not the right way to do it.  You should include some thoughts of your own about it, for example at what point you ran into difficulty with it. $\qquad$

Comment: "We say O is open if for every c∈O, there exists ϵ>0 such that Bϵ={x∈R:|x−c|<ϵ}=(c−ϵ,c+ϵ) is contained in O."  So... prove that is true for every point in (1,2)..  Is it true for $1.2?$ is it true for $1.0001$   For $1.9$?  For $c; 1< c < 2$

Answer (score 1):

Pick any $x \in (1,2)$ and let $\epsilon < \min\{x-1,2-x\}$.

Then $B_\epsilon(x) \subset (1,2)$ since $x+\epsilon < 2$ and $x - \epsilon > 1$.